# Entity FrameWork 6 Update FK Value

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to update the Fk Value using EF code First but it's not updated as Following:

```
public  class Session : BaseEntity<Int64>
{

  public virtual bool? IsGregorian { get; set; }
  public string SessionNumber { get; set; }
  public string SessionSubject { get; set; }
  public string AboutSession { get; set; }
  public DateTime? SessionDate { get; set; }
  public string SessionDateHej { get; set; }
  public System.Object SessionStartTime { get; set; }
  public System.Object SessionDuration { get; set; }
  public virtual Building Building { get; set; }
  public virtual Hall Hall { get; set; }
  public virtual FormationCouncil FormationCouncil { get; set; }
  public DateTime? ApologyStartDate { get; set; }
  public string ApologyStartDateHej { get; set; }
  public DateTime? ApologyEndDate { get; set; }
  public string ApologyEndDateHej { get; set; }
  public System.Object ApologyStartTime { get; set; }
  public System.Object ApologyEndTime { get; set; }
  public DateTime? SessionTime { get; set; }
  public virtual bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
  public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }
  public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }

}
```

public class SessionFile : BaseEntity
    {

```
    public virtual Session Session { get; set; }
    public string MemberAllowedToSee { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string SubFileName { get; set; }
    public string ContentSize { get; set; }
    public virtual bool?  IsDeleted { get; set; }

}
```

```
     SessionFile sessionFile = new SessionFile();
                        sessionFile.ID = int.Parse(item["ID"].ToString());
                        sessionFile.Name = item["Name"].ToString();
                        sessionFile.Url = item["Url"].ToString();
                        var SessionObj = _db.Sessions.First(p => p.ID == session.ID);
                        sessionFile.Session=SessionObj
                        sessionFile.IsDeleted = false;
                        sessionFile.MemberAllowedToSee =(item["MemberAllowedToSee"]!=null && item["MemberAllowedToSee"]!=string.Empty)?item["MemberAllowedToSee"].ToString().Replace("{", string.Empty).Replace("[", string.Empty).Replace("]", string.Empty).Replace("}", string.Empty).Replace(" ", string.Empty):"0";
                        _db.Entry(sessionFile).State = sessionFile.ID == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
                        var FileUplodedInfoResult = _db.SaveChanges();
```

but when i see the trace for sql i found:

```
sp_executesql N'UPDATE [dbo].[SessionFiles]
SET [MemberAllowedToSee] = @0, [Name] = @1, [Url] = @2, [SubFileName] = NULL, 
[ContentSize] = NULL, [IsDeleted] = @3
 WHERE ([ID] = @4)
```

so the Session_ID Fk in SessionFile Table not updated because not in update statement how i can pass the Session_ID in SessionFile Table to update it

Thank in advance

Comment: After `var SessionObj = _db.Sessions.First(p => p.ID == session.ID);` is `SessionObj` definitely not null?

Comment: And you should read these articles before you determine not to use foreign keys in your entity classes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh708747.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx

Comment: yes Sure not null because it's Master table